# How can I do custom routes?

Tags: magento

So I looked at how to do a hello world custom module and I understand that the standard url structure looks like /modulefrontname/controller/action
but how can I do some custom routes for my specific module.

For example
/modulefrontname/{anyparamater}
or
/modulefrontname/controller/{anyparamater}

I've seen lots of questions on stack overflow on this but most are either unanswered or they dodge the question saying its not possible without overriding the main router.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add own Router to the list of Routers used by Magento.
To do this, you will need to edit your module **etc/config.xml** file. After you have defined your routers **frontName** in the  section:

```
<frontend>
<routers>
    <modulename>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Package_Modulename</module>
            <frontName>yourFrontName</frontName>
        </args>
    </modulename>
</routers>
</frontend>
```

You can add your own Router via the events in the  section:

```
<global>
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <your_observer_code>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Package_Modulename_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </your_observer_code>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
</global>
```

Then create that file at: **Package/Modulename/Controller/Router.php** and it should extend from: **Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract**:

class Package_Modulename_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {

}

Define your method which will be called on the event: **controller_front_init_routers**:

```
public function initControllerRouters($observer)
{
    $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
    //Use the same class as Router
    $yourRouter = new Package_Modulename_Controller_Observer();
    $front->addRouter('yourRouter', $yourRouter);
}
```

And you must implement the method: match in the same class cause as it is an Observer, it is also your custom Router:

```
public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
    $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
    //Work with the $identifier and if it matches some of your custom defined URL's, you can set the found controller like this:
    if ($identifier == 'some-of-yours/custom-urls') {
        $request->setModuleName('modulename') //Your modulename
                    ->setControllerName('index') //Your controller: Package_Modulename_IndexController
                    ->setActionName('view') // The controller action
                    ->setParam('foo', 'bar'); //Set params
        $request->setAlias(
            Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
            $identifier
        );
        //You must return true if the identifier matches.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the match method you can use a model from your module to find any custom URL's stored in the database. Have a look at this Router how it works: **app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Controller/Router.php** which is added same as yours.

Then in your controller: **app/code/local/Package/Modulename/controllers/IndexController.php** you can define the **viewAction** method and use the passed parameters:

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $foo = $this->getRequest()->getParam('foo');
    //Here goes your logic
}
```

Comment: `$request->setModuleName('modulename')`
should be 

`$request->setModuleName('yourFrontName')`